# Show number of partitions in AWS Glue Table?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to get a total count of the partitions from a AWS Glue table? I was trying to find a way using the Athena console but doesn't seem possible. My other option is to try to connect to the glue table using JDBC or python and see if I can retrieve the count but it sounds overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Athena version 1 then you can use below queries to fetch the partition count :

If you have only one partition column then use below query

```
select max(partition_number) from  information_schema.__internal_partitions__ WHERE table_schema = '<db-name>'
        AND table_name = '<table-name>'
```

If you have nested partitions then use below query

```
select count(*) from  information_schema.__internal_partitions__ WHERE table_schema = '<db-name>'
        AND table_name = '<table-name>'
```